# How can I override the Identity with a custom MembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

So I've written a custom `MembershipProvider` in my ASP.NET MVC4 app which uses FormsAuthentication. The provider allows the user to login both by phone number, email and username. The thing is I want `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to be set to the username even if the user logs in by phone number or email. It is not.

I have tried overriding `MembershipUser GetUser(string, bool)` in the MembershipProvider to return a `MembershipUser`-object with the `Name` set to the username in all three cases, but it doesn't seem to matter. The identity-name is still set to whatever the user enters as login credentials.

Any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: please add your login action source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is set to the username stored in the Forms Authentication cookie.

The code that creates the Forms Authentication cookie (typically a call to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` or `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` in a POST Action of the Controller that handles the login) should provide the username you want to use, irrespective of whether the user has supplied a phone number, email or username.